# imagegif() not uploading to site

Tags: php

So, I'm working on an avatar script for my site and am trying to get avatars by URL to upload to the site. I already made sure that everything (fopen or something along those lines) was allowed, but it just doesn't seem to upload. I have a feeling that the problem is the process file is in /settings/process.php while it's trying to upload to /useravatar, but I'm not really sure. Also, query(), getuserdata(), and getmydata() are working fine in the code, as they are functions in the included session.php

Here's my code:

```
include('../session.php');
$pictureurl = $_POST['urlava'];
# CHECK THAT FILE IS NOT ACCESED DIRECTLY
if(isset($pictureurl)){
// CHECK IF POST IS "HTTP://" ONLY
if($pictureurl == 'http://'){
# IF YES, END SCRIPT
die("Error!");
}
# CHECK IF IT'S AN URL (HTTP/HTTPS)
$checkifurl = parse_url($pictureurl);
if($checkifurl['scheme'] == "http" || $checkifurl['scheme'] == "https"){
# CHECK IF IT'S AN IMAGE (PNG/JPG/JPEG/GIF/MPO)
$url = pathinfo($pictureurl);
if($url['extension'] == 'png' || $url['extension'] == 'jpg' || $url['extension'] == 'jpeg' || $url['extension'] == 'gif' || $url['extension'] == 'mpo'){
# DELETE CURRENT AVATAR
if(getuserdata($_SESSION['username'], avatar) == '/images/default.png'){
}else{
$file = substr(getmydata(avatar), 1);
unlink($file);
}
$randomstring = generateRandStr(5);
# CREATE NEW AVATAR
$img = file_get_contents($pictureurl);
$im = imagecreatefromstring($img);
$width = imagesx($im);
$height = imagesy($im);
$newwidth = '50';
$newheight = '50';
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
    $filename = "/useravatar/".strtolower(getmydata(username))."-".$randomstring.".gif"; // I think the problem is here
imagecopyresampled($thumb, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
imagegif($thumb,$filename); // But it can also be here
imagedestroy($thumb);
imagedestroy($im);
# UPDATE AVATAR
query("UPDATE members SET avatar='$filename' WHERE username='$_SESSION[username]'");

}
}
}
header("Location: avatar.php?updated=1");
```

It may seem messy, because it probably is. This script worked before, so I'm unsure why it doesn't work now. If anyone could help, that would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check the file and dir permissions. Add **error_reporting(E_ALL)** and **ini_set('display_errors', true);** to find it out

Comment: @AdrianPreuß It returns nothing.

Comment: have u an working example (online) to check this?

Comment: Yes, but you have to register to my site to do so.
http://ar7comm.tk
After registration
http://ar7comm.tk/settings/avatar.php

Comment: is the script returning "Error!" everytime?

Comment: @anurupr No, it's just uploading nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is the Permissions.

```
 Warning: unlink(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File() is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/customers/webs/ni235658_1/ring/ar7comm/:/var/customers/tmp/ni235658_1/:/usr/share/php/:/usr/share/php5/:/tmp/) in /var/customers/webs/ni235658_1/ring/ar7comm/settings/process.php on line 23

 Warning: imagegif(): Unable to open '/useravatar/-57Kkf.gif' for writing: No such file or directory in /var/customers/webs/ni235658_1/ring/ar7comm/settings/process.php on line 36
```

Check it out: http://secondchoice.de/ click on **POST** insert the **Url** http://ar7comm.tk/settings/process.php and set the **Parameter** urlava with an Image url

Try to add the full path:

```
 imagegif($thumb, dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . $filename);
```

Comment: Nope. Still getting the same result.

Comment: Yeah, can you Debug? **settingsuseravatar** /-5o08X.gif a Slash must be set, but you have that removed from **$filename**! (see the update)

Comment: I'm sorry, that was nonsense to  me.

Oh, and also, it's not supposed to insert as just -*random*, it's supposed to be /*username*-*random*

I see what you said now, but with the edit, it doesn't work.

Oh, and what do the permissions have to be to upload to a folder?

Comment: the executed user must have write access. For testing you can set it to **0766** or **0777**

Comment: I tried that, and I also found that the database is inserting this as the avatar column for my user:

/useravatar/angelrulez7-uWP0B.gif, but yet, it doesn't exist on the server.

Comment: generally you have problems with your webspace. Contact your provider. You scripts must comply with the open_basedir restrictions.

Comment: I actually need to ask my friend because he hosts the site, so I'll do that.

Comment: try imagegif($thumb, dirname(dirname(\_\_FILE\_\_)) . '/' . $filename);

Comment: Works ;) That was the problem... You was in the directory /settings/. In /settings/ exists no sub-directory with the name "useravatar". This is one up!